# How to select only the first max value in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to make an operation on a cell and I choose the one with the maximum value.

If it happens that there are more than one cell with the max value I need to do the operation only to the first one, how can I do that?

ie: in the imag at the row 6 I need to sum the coloured value (the CHK column) to one of the max value (A6:L6) that is 12. But in this interval I have two cells with value 12 and I need to sum only to one of those

[image]

I use excel 2007 on window 7

Comment: what "need to do an operation" means? do you format it manually -> in this case select the first one. Do you use it in a formula to perform a calculation? -> in this case the value will be the same whichever you choose. Please describe your question better and also add some sample data and desired output.

Comment: All I can say is what? This makes no sense. Please show the code you're using, some demo data, anything. As it is, I'm voting to close as it's so unclear. If there is more than 1 max, why does it matter which max you return, it's the same number?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer as written.  You need some formula that is based on using the max value once, but your example makes no sense to anyone but yourself.  Without clarifying the logic that gives you a "1" for that row and "0" for all others, there is no way to help with the formula.

Comment: I need to sum the calue in the CHK column (-1 or 1 or 0 for each row) to a random value for each row. I would like to sum it to one of the biggests

Comment: How is it random if you are selecting the max value?  What and where is the result?  Please show a complete example, that explains what's there, the logic and relationships, how you want to use the numbers, what the result would be for that example, and how you got to that result.

Answer (score 3):

Go and look for the `max()` and `match()` it then. It will return you the cell number.

For example: `=MATCH(MAX(A6:I6);A6:I6;0)`

[image: Match the maximum]!

---

**Syntax**

```
MATCH(SearchCriterion; LookupArray; Type)
```

> Type = 0, only exact matches are found.

If the search criterion is found more than once, the function returns the index of the **first matching value**.

Comment: I'll add a picture for explanation as soon I have enough credit.

Comment: Post a link to the image at any publicly-accesible sharing service (like imgur.com), and someone here will add it for you.

Comment: Thx @fixer1234 got it already.

Comment: That's really neat! +1

Comment: Does it it answer your question?

Comment: A picture was added to the question after your answer.  You might want to modify your answer so that it's row-based rather than column-based, which might give the OP a clue to accomplishing the objective, although what that might be is totally unclear.

Comment: done... though I still don't really get it...